# SQL Can I join an Integer to a non integer in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer

Hello all I have a client where they have given me the following SQL code..

```
select top 10 a.Login as Agent_Name, CallDateTime, h.PhoneNum as Client_DDI, ConnectTime, BridgeTime, CRC, *

from history h 
join Agent a on h.AgentID = a.AgentID
join contact c on h.DialID = c.trans_dialid

where h.PhoneNum = '01619740881'


order by h.CallDateTime desc
```

it fails as h.dialid is a none integer but still a number but c.trans_dialid is a standard integer, is there a way to essentially place ' ' around the h.dialid before it joins?

updated and error added.
Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The conversion of the varchar value '-8956468456' overflowed an int column.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using (which is presumably SQL Server).

Comment: could you do `CAST(h.DialID AS INT)`?

Comment: Some RDBMs (if not all) will do an implicit convertion but if only one data (from the string column) has a value that is not an integer it will break which seems to be your case.

Comment: If you need to do that join my tip is to take a closer look at the table design. An integer column is usually supposed to be joined with another integer column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `join` columns of different types.  After all, the error that you are getting is a *run-time* error not a *compile-time* error, so the syntax is allowed.  This isn't a good idea, but I'll get to that.

Your problem is that the conversion fails.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can handle this using `try_convert()`:

```
on try_convert(int, h.dialid) = c.trans_dialid
```

If the values are supposed to be integers with no leading zeros, then an explicit conversion to a string is a good solution:

```
on cast(h.dialid as varchar(255)) = c.trans_dialid
```

But really, you should fix your data structure.  Columns used for joining should be of the same type.  This is very, very important for performance reasons.  By  using different types, you prevent the optimizer from using particular optimizations.

As important, when one table refers to another, then you should have an explicit foreign key relationship.  This relationship requires that the two keys have the same type.  So, set up your database correctly, and you will not have this problem.